# Can OpenMath-Objects be compared to another in terms of equality?

Tags: java, xml, math, mathjax, mathml

im actually interested in comparing two OpenMath-Objects with each other in terms of equality (despite being build a bit differently in XML) by using Java.

For example i want "x^2+2x-35=0" to be equal to "-35+2x+x^2=0".

So im wondering if there is a way to achieve this. I at least understand OpenMath as some sort of tree structure and thought there might be a way to compare them.

I already tried writing the expressions for those two equations, but ended up with no luck or good idea.

```
Equation 1: x^2+2x-35=0
<OMOBJ xmlns='http://www.openmath.org/OpenMath' version='2.0' cdbase='http://www.openmath.org/cd'>
    <OMA>
        <OMS cd='relation1' name='eq'/>
        <OMA>
            <OMS cd='arith1' name='minus'/>
            <OMA>
                <OMS cd='arith1' name='plus'/>
                <OMA>
                    <OMS cd='arith1' name='power'/>
                    <OMV name='x'/>
                    <OMI>
                        2
                    </OMI>
                </OMA>
                <OMA style='invisible'>
                    <OMS cd='arith1' name='times'/>
                    <OMI>
                        2
                    </OMI>
                    <OMV name='x'/>
                </OMA>
            </OMA>
            <OMI>
                35
            </OMI>
        </OMA>
        <OMI>
            0
        </OMI>
    </OMA>
</OMOBJ>

Equation 2: -35+2x+x^2
<OMOBJ xmlns='http://www.openmath.org/OpenMath' version='2.0' cdbase='http://www.openmath.org/cd'>
    <OMA>
        <OMS cd='relation1' name='eq'/>
        <OMA>
            <OMS cd='arith1' name='plus'/>
            <OMA>
                <OMS cd='arith1' name='unary_minus'/>
                <OMI>
                    35
                </OMI>
            </OMA>
            <OMA style='invisible'>
                <OMS cd='arith1' name='times'/>
                <OMI>
                    2
                </OMI>
                <OMV name='x'/>
            </OMA>
            <OMA>
                <OMS cd='arith1' name='power'/>
                <OMV name='x'/>
                <OMI>
                    2
                </OMI>
            </OMA>
        </OMA>
        <OMI>
            0
        </OMI>
    </OMA>
</OMOBJ>
```

Thank you for your time

Sincerely

Phu

Answer (score 0):

### General solution

Checking if mathematical objects are equal could be an unsolvable problem. However, from how you formulated your question, I will assume that you were comparing relatively simple objects, like polynomial equations.

You didn't tell how you are storing the XML tree, so I will give you an implementation agnostic solution (In fact, depending on your internal representation of the tree, you might even want a separate representation to manipulate it).

The best way to achieve what you want would be to define a normalized form for any kind of object you want to compare, and **compare the formalized forms**.

### Example: Polynomial equations

A possible normal form for polynomial equations could be this:

- The right side of the equation is always zero.
- The left side of the equation has a minimal form.
- The left side monomials are ordered by degree.

So for an equation like `5x + x^2 - 3x = -8` the normalized form would be `x^2 + 2x + 8 = 0`.

To implement a normalization algorithm like this is not trivial. My suggestion would be to implement the following functions:

- One function to check the degree of a monomial (`3`->`0`, `2x`->`1`, `x^2`->`2`, etc).
- A function to reduce monomials of the same degree to its minimal form (`4x + 2x`->`6x`).
- A function to translate all subtractions into additions with a unary_minus in the second operand (`5 - 3`->`5 + (-3)`).
- A function to flatten applications of additions (`(1 + 2) + 3`->`1 + 2 + 3`).
- A function to change the sign of a monomial: add an application of unary_minus if there is none, or remove it if there is (`4`->`(-4)`).

And finally implement this algorithm:

1. On both sides, translate all subtractions into additions in both sides and flatten them.
2. Change the sign of all monomials in right side and bring them to the left side. Replace the whole right side with a single zero.
3. Sort the left side monomials by degree.
4. Reduce the monomials with the same degree (that are now consecutive).

With this normalizing function, you can compare any polynomial equation, no matter how the XML is built.

---

### TL;DR

To compare mathematical objects that are built differently, you must use a normalized form of said objects. So unfortunately there is no an easy way to do it.